# Testing v-slots with v-for - Jest / Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I am trying to figure out how to test my component which has v-slot in it. 
Structure of component template:

**Grid.vue**

```
<div> 
   <v-slot>
</div>
```

And when I call it it is something like:

```
<Grid>
   <Column v-for="(element, index) in list" :key=index /> 
</Grid>
```

So far I've got that :

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Grid from '~/components/Grid';
import GridColumn from '~/components/Column';

const columns = [
    {
        id: 'col1',
    },
    {
        id: 'col2',
    },
];

describe('Grid.vue', () => {
    const columnWrapper = {
        // render(h) {
        //     return columns.map(function (item) {
        //         return h('Column', item.id) })
        // }
        render(h) {
            return h(Column, { props: { index: 1, column: columns[0] } });
        }
    };

    const wrapper = mount(Grid, {
        slots: { columnWrapper }
    });
});
```

I did write 2 ways of rendering slots for `Grid`. The second one with `return h(Column....` is creating only one column. How could I render columns = number of columns model list ? The first option / commented I am not sure If I have written it well - `return h('Column' ....` - that might be wrong.

When I console log `wrapper.vm.$el.children` the `HTMLCollection` is empty. Columns weren't added into `Grid`. Does any one know what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `v-slot` is new directive and not a built-in component

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not clear what do you want to achieve with that test, it looks complicated.
If you want to test just `Grid` component or initialize it with some slots I recommend to write something readable and avoid other components usage:

```
// example
const wrapper = mount(Grid, {
    slots: {
       default: columns.map(c => `<div class="foo">${c.id}</div>`)
    }
});

expect(wrapper.findAll('.foo').length).toBe(2)
```

If you want to test this part:

```
// for example, GridUsage.vue
<Grid>
   <Column v-for="(element, index) in list" :key=index /> 
</Grid>
```

So just test a component where this usage exists, it's not responsibility of `Grid.vue`

```
// example part of test file
const columns = [
   {
      id: 'col1',
   },
   {
      id: 'col2',
   },
];
const wrapper = mount(GridUsage, { propsData: { list: columns  } });
expect(wrapper.findAll(Column).length).toBe(2)
```

And, of course, there should be a separate test for `Column.vue`

Docs: [Vue Test Utils-Mounting Options-Slots](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#slots)